# modal 'show.bs.modal' event gets called before click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a modal in my code and it gets called like this

```
$('a.loan-application-view-toggle[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function() {
    $('#loan-application-view-modal').data('show-id', $(this).data('id'));
    $('#loan-application-view-modal').data('detailsID', $(this).data('assignmentid'));
});
```

But i also have this event in my javascript as well

```
$('#loan-application-view-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

})
```

And after a while it overrides my click event

Comment: Could you please create JS fiddle so we can test it.

Comment: What do you mean after while it overrides your click event? Can you be more specific as to the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. Bootstrap binds click handler on `[data-toggle="modal"]` element which triggers the `show.bs.modal` event. This handler is registered before yours and is therefore called before your click event handler.

Comment: so how do i make my click event happen before the data-toggle event?